# report on date column with gap

Tags: c#, sql, linq

there is my columns

```
Id | date | location
```

and some of rows :

```
1 | 2016/09/08 14:02:08 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:03:08 | CA
1 | 2016/09/08 14:05:08 | SI
1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:05 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:09 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:22 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:09:08 | SI
1 | 2016/09/08 14:23:08 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:25:08 | LA
```

i want to know that :

```
"where was user at least every 5 minutes"
```

so my result is :

```
1 | 2016/09/08 14:02:08 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:09 | NY
1 | 2016/09/08 14:23:08 | NY
```

i don't want any more rows between my results.

so, how can i do that ?
any solution such as "SQL Query", "LinQ Expression", "C# code", ... will be helpful.

thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried something like " Thomas Ayoub " answer. 
filter rows after read from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the class:

```
public class LocationInformation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Guy with ID : ({0}), was near {1} at {2}", ID, Location, Date);
    }
}
```

And the function:

```
public static void Locate(List<LocationInformation> myInformations, int id)
{
    DateTime lastCheck = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (LocationInformation locationInformation in myInformations.Where(i => i.ID == id).OrderBy(i => i.Date))
    {
        // Less than 5 min check
        if (locationInformation.Date < lastCheck.AddMinutes(5))
        {
            continue;
        }
        lastCheck = locationInformation.Date;
        Console.Out.WriteLine(locationInformation);
    }
}
```

This will do the work.

Comment: thank you.
and yes this is a good solution.
but if my rows insert in every seconds, my database result can be very big and if my users grow up, the query result will take a long time.
i'm looking for a solution that can filter database rows before fetching them first of all. but plan B is your solution ;)

Comment: *my database result can be very big* => how big? @Bojbaj

Comment: about 3000x15x[number of users] location rows per day
and about 240,000 user

Comment: @Bojbaj and you do check for the 240k users everyday?

Comment: absolutely not.
but don't you agree it will better performance if i can filter results before database fetch ?
in this example i need 12x15 row per user and i have 3000x15 rows.

Comment: @Bojbaj the better would be to only record values that are at least 5 minutes distant (unless you need this precision in other part of your application)...

Comment: unfortunately this number is a part of report filter and 5 minutes is an example.
user can select gaps, and also can fetch report without any gap.
in other hand i am interested to find out a solution for database ( not only for this project, i want to know that for my curious )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            string[] inputs = { 
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:02:08 | NY",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:03:08 | CA",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:05:08 | SI",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:05 | NY",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:09 | NY",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:07:22 | NY",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:09:08 | SI",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:23:08 | NY",
                "1 | 2016/09/08 14:25:08 | LA"
                             };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("location", typeof(string));

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                string[] splitRow = input.Split(new char[] {'|'});
                dt.Rows.Add( new object[] {
                    int.Parse(splitRow[0]),
                    DateTime.Parse(splitRow[1]),
                    splitRow[2].Trim()
                });
            }
            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("location"))
                .Select(x => new {
                    id = x.First().Field<int>("Id"),
                    location = x.First().Field<string>("location"),
                    times = x.Select(y => y.Field<DateTime>("date")).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DateTime lastTime = new DateTime();
                foreach (var date in group.times)
                {
                    if (lastTime.AddMinutes(5) <= date)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",  new string[] { group.id.ToString(), group.location, date.ToString()}));
                        lastTime = date;
                    }

                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```